# Regular Expressions: Return Null when a group does not appear

Tags: c#, regex

After a week struggling with this problem, I need help with this pattern:

```
"^(?<Id>\d+) - (?<Agent>.*)(?<Registry>\(S (.*)\))+?. \((?<Date>\d{2}[/]\d{2}[/]\d{4})\).?$"
```

My test with https://regex101.com/:

Case 1:

121971 - my text(S 8, H M 42670). (27/06/1974)

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Match 1 | 0-46 | 121971 - my text(S 8, H M 42670). (27/06/1974) |
| Group 1 | 19-31 | 8, H M 42670 |
| Group Id | 0-6 | 121971 |
| Group Agent | 9-16 | my text |
| Group Registry | 16-32 | (S 8, H M 42670) |
| Group Date | 35-45 | 27/06/1974 |

Case 2:

2 - Lorem Ipsum. (19/12/2022).

regex101 returns "Your regular expression does not match the subject string."

I removed last + of group "(?(S (.*)))?.". Case 1 joins Agent and Registry in same group. Case 2 returns:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Match 1 | 0-30 | 2 - Lorem Ipsum. (19/12/2022). |
| Group Id | 0-1 | 2 |
| Group Agent | 4-15 | Lorem Ipsum |
| Group Date | 18-28 | 19/12/2022 |

This is expected output:

| Group | Case 1 | Case 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Id | 121971 | 2 |
| Agent | my text | Lorem Ipsum |
| Registry | S 8, H M 42670 | [null] |
| Date | 27/06/1974 | 19/12/2022 |

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cs
^(?<Id>\d+) - (?<Agent>.*?)(?:\((?<Registry>[^()]*)\))?\W*\((?<Date>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})\)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cwHlIy/1). If you have `.?` at the end to match an optional CR char, you can just use `\r?` (in case you compile the pattern with `RegexOptions.Multiline` option).

*Details*:

- `^(?<Id>\d+)` - Group "Id": one or more digits
- `-` - a hyphen enclosed with a single regular space
- `(?<Agent>.*?)` - Group "Agent": any zero or more chars other than a newline char, as few as possible
- `(?:\((?<Registry>[^()]*)\))?` - an optional group matching

  - `\(` - a `(` char
  - `(?<Registry>[^()]*)` - Group "Registry": any zero or more chars other than `)` and `(`
  - `\)` - a `)` char
- `\W*` - zero or more non-word chars
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `(?<Date>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})` - Group "Date": two digits, `/`, two digits, `/` and four digits
- `\)` - a `)` char
- `$` - end of string.